# How apply ng-annotate and then uglify inside gulp-if?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-useref, gulp-if

Here is my minification gulp task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
useref = require('gulp-useref'),
gulpif = require('gulp-if'),
uglify = require('gulp-uglify'),
minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css'),
ngmin = require('gulp-ngmin'),
ngAnnotate = require('gulp-ng-annotate');

gulp.task('minifyAll', function () {
    return gulp.src('app/*.html')
        .pipe(useref())
        .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify(ngAnnotate())))
        .pipe(gulpif('*.css', minifyCss()))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

In case of js-file I want to move it through ng-annotate first and uglify then. I am new to gulp, that's why I don't know how to do it correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found solution. Maybe it is not the best, but at least it works.

```
gulp.task('minifyAll', function () {
return gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(useref())
    .pipe(gulpif('*.js', ngAnnotate()))
    .pipe(gulpif('*.js', uglify()))
    .pipe(gulpif('*.css', minifyCss()))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```